# Loading excel file with a variable containg space in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have an excel file that looks like this:

```
A    B         C    
ID   Name  Description
 1   Jane  She is the headmaster of the school
```

Now I want to load this into R.
I have saved the excel file as text and typed in the following command:

```
df<-read.table("excelFileName.txt", header=T)
```

R would then complain that there are more columns than column headings.  If I want to keep the last variable as a string, how can I do this?  And is it still possible to load the file in R?

Comment: Maybe you can make your life easier with the `xlsx` package that allows you to load excel file in R.

Comment: Presumably the text file is tab delimited, in which case you need to add \t as the separator `df<-read.table("excelFileName.txt", header=T, sep="\t")`

Comment: Or assuming you have a txt file separated by comma, try `sep=","`

Comment: Check out the `readxl` package and its `read_excel()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current txt(csv) file :

```
   A    B                                   C
1 ID Name                          Description
2  1 Jane She is the headmaster of the school
```

Example dataset :

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "ID"), class = "factor"), 
    B = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Jane", "Name"), class = "factor"), 
    C = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Description", "She is the headmaster of the school"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Read.table :

```
df<-read.table("excelFileName.txt", header=T, sep = ",")
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further?  What does the code mean? what are 2L, 1L?  thank you!!

Comment: @Headandtoes The 2L is just a classification of an integer.  The Example data set section of code is just the `dput` of the sample data set I made in excel and imported.  If I were you, I would check what the separation is for the text file.  It would be `.` or `,` or `tab` or `space`, or others.  Check out what the delimiter-separator is : see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values

Comment: @Head and toes...sorry see above